# Sugarcrm rest api. login attempt failed please check the username and password

Tags: sugarcrm

i have read documentation and post about the rest api but didn't find any answer to my issue.

the command i have use to test it :

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"encrypted md5"},"application_name":"dummy"}" http://myhost/service/v2/rest.php`

i have checked the admin password in the users table.

sugarCE is 6.5.0 (build 8338)

what do i need to check next ?
thanks

Comment: i did the same request with Asakusuma wrapper and it works fine. i can't figure what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this. I have replaced the double quote with single quotes.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d 'method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3"},"application_name":"dummy"}' http://localhost:8888/SugarCE-Full-6.5.15/service/v2/rest.php
```

and the sample output is:

```
{
    "id": "dc67f918eb13843fbc7446ed4e3e4cf0", 
    "module_name": "Users", 
    "name_value_list": {
        "user_currency_id": {
            "name": "user_currency_id", 
            "value": "-99"
        }, 
        "user_currency_name": {
            "name": "user_currency_name", 
            "value": "US Dollars"
        }, 
        "user_id": {
            "name": "user_id", 
            "value": "1"
        }, 
        "user_language": {
            "name": "user_language", 
            "value": "en_us"
        }, 
        "user_name": {
            "name": "user_name", 
            "value": "admin"
        }
    }
}
```